# How are information decrypted when the certificate is stored in Windows certificate store

Tags: windows, ssl, encryption, x509certificate

I'm trying to learn a little about Windows application development, and I have yet to wrap my head around certificate handling.

Is encryption and decryption handled by Windows OS functions, or by fetching the private key from the store and performing the cryptographic tasks separately?

An example: assume I have some web page hosted with IIS using SSL certs.
Is e.g. the IIS web server using api calls like the one below, or does IIS ask the OS to encrypt/decrypt using some user selected cert from the store?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsaprivatekey?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I na given case, IIS acquires private key handle and calls CrypoAPI functions to performs cryptographic operations. Though, IIS doesn't use referenced API, it uses native functions directly.

Windows uses abstraction layer by defining APIs for cryptography and one important part of these APIs is key handle. OS may not have access to raw key material and use key handle to access the key by key owner. Key owners are implemented as Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) or modern Key Storage Provider (KSP). When necessary, OS calls implemented API and pass key handle to CSP or KSP. Then CSP/KSP implementation is responsible for raw key material access actual cryptographic operations. CSP/KSP implementation is vendor-specific. Windows ships a dozen of software-based CSP/KSP implementations and 3rd party vendors may ship their own implementation, especially when key stored on a hardware (smart card or HSM).

In any way, OS don't care how and where the key is stored, it simply calls defined API, passes key handle and input parameters. CSP/KSP then accesses raw key material, perform requested operation and return result back to caller.

And here is the answer to your question: cryptography operations are handled by CSP/KSP that owns/stores particular key identified by key handle. Whether it is OS or not depends on CSP/KSP implementation. If it is software, then most likely (not necessary, but very often) it is handled by OS. If it is hardware, then it is handled by hardware itself.

Comment: So in the IIS case, every call to e.g. a rest api over an ssl connection  would in turn trigger a crypto api call to Windows?

Comment: not every call. Private key is used for TLS handshare and session key generation. For subsequent HTTP calls cached session key is used.